# Material nodes - make a range of values?

Tags: materials, node-editor, mathematics

Ok, Im trying to fake volumetric light shafts using this node setup and a gradient texture made in photoshop:

[image]

Basically this still looks not great, and I want to have a "gradient" of the emission strength, emanating out from the bottom. It's almost as if I need to convert the black/white of the gradient to a value? How could I do this? Currently:

[image]

Comment: Blender has a built in gradient texture that you should be able to map exactly like you have the image texture now. That will allow you some more control I would think. You may want to look into the colorramp node as well, as that will also help you control the gradients.

Comment: That said, I would suggest using faked volumetrics if you want a nice light beam, such as in this tutorial here: https://cloud.blender.org/p/caminandes-3/56c6da5cc379cf0079716873. It's still really fast, and will help avoid a bunch of issues that can arise when using surface emissions (being able to see through parts of the object, or needing a denser mesh for example).

Comment: I created a short tutorial video a while ago that may help with using and controlling ColorRamp and Gradients to make volumetic type effects.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=cPvYAHc9vCE